# How to show iPhone screen on projector?

Tags: iphone, projector

I want to do some user training on the new iPhone they are getting and I would like to be able to display the screen up on a projector while I am talking, similar to a Steve Jobs keynote.

Is there a way to do this without jail breaking?

Specifically, I would like to do this on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the iPhone Dev Tools and use the emulator, this is supposedly what Steve Jobs does his presentations with (I haven't corroborated that). Otherwise you will need to jailbreak and use one of the VNC apps.

I know it sounds like you do not want to jailbreak, but you could do it just for the presentation, then go back to stock IOS afterwords. No one would know you were jailbroken except for the savy.

[Update]
Forgot to add, follow this link for what to do once jailbroke:
http://www.mp3car.com/vbulletin/iphone-mobile-osx-meshing-connect-your-car-internet-cloud/128589-mirror-your-iphone-display-extneral-display.html#post1286663

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Apple 30-pin to VGA adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC552ZM/B/apple-vga-adapter) to show your iPhone's screen on the projector. It doesn't show the bezel like Steve's demo phone or the Simulator do, but it'll show what's on the screen.